# Login With MVVM and WPF - Login Object must use in other windows. (Globalization)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, authentication, globalization

I am very new to WPF and MVVM Pattern.  I even have no experience on windows.

I have Created Simple login window

_ Login.xaml, LoginViewModel.cs

_ Dashboard.xaml, DashboardViewModel.cs

After Login Successfully - ( In Login time we will select Language also )

I am Displaying  Username & Selected Language in Dashboard window

I wrote code like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        try
        {
            var login = new Login();
            var loginVM = new LoginViewModel();
            Dashboard main = null;
            loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                DashboardViewModel dvModel = new DashboardViewModel(loginVM);
                main = new Dashboard();
                main.DataContext = dvModel;
                main.ShowDialog();
                login.Hide();
            };
            login.DataContext = loginVM;
            login.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In Dashboard Window it is displaying username and Language successfully.

But my problem is those two (Username & Language) properties I want to use in dashboard codebehind for update the layout based on language & other xaml files or other viewmodels . How to do that one ?

Technically I want to use Loginviewmodel object in all viewmodels.

Based on Selected Language I want to update Layout.

Note: Is this login approach good ? Is there any alternative for Globalization in MVVM pattern ?

Comment: Hi, not for beeing Mr. Picky PickyNose here, but you should *never* just rethrow your ex in your catch block, only throw is worse, well beside just consuming the exception in an empty try catch block. Rather do a throw new Exception("Failed to init loginscreen or whatever", ex);  When it comes to globalization in WPF and the SL fauna, we are struggeling with well some corny ways of handling this, it's different from platform to platform. See @Troels Larsens post below.

Answer (score 2):

Using a ViewModel for login is perfectly valid. I would perhaps create a token in your loginVM to pass around the system, depending on your needs. That token should be passed into the constructors of your other viewmodels from your main view model (DashboardViewModel?). This can be resolved using any decent IoC container.

For globalization/localization, I would use resources (in satellite assemblies). We've experimented with various things, and found that we didn't like the WPF UUIDs added everywhere when using LocBaml. And storing translation is a database quickly became a performance hog (even when loading in bulk). This does require you to find your labels etc. to a resource manager, but in my opinion, it is worth it.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files), for a nice extension, that enables you to simply write:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Resx MyText}"/>
```

And it will be translated using resource files.

An alterative approach is to simply store the Username and Language is a static property. I know most people don't like globals, but something like this is in nature very global, and you will still be able to inject it in if you so desire. The downside of this approach is that your unit tests would have to setup this static variable first.

**EDIT** An example of the static approach:

```
public static class RuntimeInfo {
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static CultureInfo UserCulture { get; set; }
}
```

In your loginVM, simply store the necessary values in a static class. This can be accessed anywhere needed. This is not as 'correct' as the previous approach, but it can be more pragmatic than having to pass the username into every single ViewModel in your application.

I still recommend injection through an IoC container though.

Comment: Could you give me any example for Last approach to apply static property on both username and Language in mvvm pattern

Comment: Been there done that, even made an own binding. Localization is a mess in WPF :(. I wonder how many approuches and hours I've used playing with the issue in both WPF and the SL fauna during the years. Heads up for your post though. Ugh "compiling" sattelite assemblies just for some language changes, what where they thinking? :)

Comment: @Stian.: Sometimes it's not about the best solution, but the least worst. ;)

Comment: @TroelsLarsen Hehe true that ;) But regarding localization in the WPF/SL fauna.. Well it's a joke is all I can say :) Using locbaml with xbap ouch don't get me started, particularly if you are dealing with large LOB applications. Each time some language change is required a fullblown build and deploy is required.